# How to listen to successful_payment messages in Telegram Bot in Televerse?

Tags: dart, telegram, telegram-bot

I am using Televerse to build Telegram bot with Dart. I'm using `televerse: ^1.11.4`

```yaml
dependencies:
  televerse: ^1.11.4
  # ...
```

When the bot successfully completes payments Telegram will send a `SuccessfulPayment` object. Here is the Telegram Bot API documentation about it: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#successfulpayment

I am not sure how to listen for this particular message. How do access the successfulPayment object?

I tried looking in the Televerse documentation and couldn't find anything related to SuccessfulPayment object. I also checked Telegram Bot API documentation and couldn't understand much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you're using the latest version of Televerse already.

Hence, there's a method just for this. You can call the `Televerse.onSuccessfulPayment` callback register to attach a listener for the SuccessfulPayment service messages.

Here's the code:

```dart
  bot.onSuccessfulPayment((ctx) {
    final successfulPayment = ctx.message.successfulPayment!;
    // Do something with the successful payment

  });
```

This callback will only be executed when the `successfulPayment` object is not null. Hope this is what you're looking for.

Happy Coding!